# No built-in function in SQL Server for "substring to the end"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Most implementations of substring support omitting the length argument, returning the substring from the nth position to the end of the string, but not SQL Server's, last time I checked.

In the year 2023, is there still no such built-in function?

One workaround is passing a large number definitely greater than the greatest possible length, but that's fragile and crude.

EDIT: because `substring(s, 3, datalength(s) - 2)` is clunkier, harder to read, and less maintainable than `substring(s, 3)`. And no, I don't think it's unreasonable to expect Microsoft to provide.

`len()`, by the way, quietly trims the trailing whitespace, which may or may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: use length of the string like an other person

Comment: It is too much to ask from Microsoft. They are missing lots of things compared to others.  You can simply use an arbitrary large value for 3rd parameter or write your own substring() say in C#.

Comment: Why would you not just use `RIGHT` ?

Comment: @PatrickHurst How would you use right in a field that was variable length and you wanted everything after the first 4 characters?

Comment: i sometimes use STUFF(somestring, 1, charindex(whatever), ''). But no, there's no substring to the end

Comment: @Kevin `SELECT RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String)-4)`

Comment: `STUFF`, in my opinion, seems to be what you want. Impossible to know without meaningful examples. Instead of wanting *all* the characters after the *n*th character, you would *remove* all the characters up to the *n*th character.

Comment: I normally just stick in a large number (e.g. 8000 for non max datatypes) - I wouldn't use `RIGHT` + `LEN` here as it probably won't do what you intended if the string has trailing spaces

Comment: @ThomA you should probably make that the answer. I never thought about using `STUFF` like that: `SELECT STUFF(@String,1,CHARINDEX(':', @String),'')`

Comment: Regarding your edit `datalength(s)` should be fine. You just need a value `>=` than the actual value. There is no benefit of calculating it precisely. And the length in bytes will be at least as big as the length in characters that you need. May be double what you need if `nvarchar` but this doesn't matter

Comment: `DATALENGTH` can give unexpected results if your data type is `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: @PatrickHurst - it doesn't matter here

Comment: @MartinSmith it does if they OP decides to use `RIGHT(@String, DATALENGTH(@String)-4)`

Comment: OK but no one apart from you has proposed that - the edit is using as the third parameter to `substring`

Comment: Literally the first comment speaks to using `LEN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `SUBSTRING` doesn't make the number characters you want optional; you must provide a value. If, however, you want all the characters after a certain one then `STUFF` would likely be a better option; you instead replace the first *n* characters with a zero length string.

Let's say you have the string `'abc-def'` in a column and wanted to the remove the first 4. You could do `SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 5, 8000)`, using an abritrary high number, or do `STUFF(YourColumn, 1, 4, '')`. The latter doesn't need an abritrary high number, and can't accidentally truncate a `MAX` length value.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T2afR8Ow)

If you wanted to remove all the characters up to the hyphen (`-`) then you would use `CHARINDEX`: `STUFF(YourColumn, 1, CHARINDEX('-',YourColumn), '')`

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A1ratPWo)

Answer (score 4):

The approach in your edit just needs a minor tweak IMO.

There is no need to do

```
substring(s, 3, datalength(s) - 3)
```

You can just do

```
substring(s, 3, datalength(s))
```

All you need for the third parameter is that it be at least as long as the number of characters to retain.

As `datalength` is the length in bytes and there is no case where the number of characters will exceed this it is safe to use.

In SQL Server 2022 you could also do

```
substring(s, 3, -1 >> 1)
```

to somewhat concisely allow for string lengths up to 2,147,483,647 characters without calculating any lengths but this definitely loses readability points.

Comment: Good point, still kinda clunky :) I like `-1 >> 1` as a maxint.

Comment: Pretty sure most of these string functions are still how they were in Sybase days and haven't had much love since!